# Override send() method in Request/Request.JSON to append defined data?

Tags: mootools

My site makes use of ajax heavily for stuff like editing user details. I want to make an admin mode so that an admin can edit the user's details without having to log in as them (and so having to know their password.)

I plan to have all the user details pages on my site take the parameter `id`. If the page visitor is logged in as an admin, I want this id to be appended to the data of all ajax requests sent. So if the user is logged in as admin, I will inject some javascript into the page after the mootools library loads that forces the Request method to always carry this id when it makes requests.

How should I implement this?

This is the send method for the Request class:

```
send: function(options){
    if (!this.check(options)) return this;

    this.options.isSuccess = this.options.isSuccess || this.isSuccess;
    this.running = true;

    var type = typeOf(options);
    if (type == 'string' || type == 'element') options = {data: options};

    var old = this.options;
    options = Object.append({data: old.data, url: old.url, method: old.method}, options);
    var data = options.data, url = String(options.url), method = options.method.toLowerCase();

    switch (typeOf(data)){
        case 'element': data = document.id(data).toQueryString(); break;
        case 'object': case 'hash': data = Object.toQueryString(data);
    }

    //---------
    //LOOK HERE
    //---------
    if (this.options.format){
        var format = 'format=' + this.options.format;
        data = (data) ? format + '&' + data : format;
    }

    if (this.options.emulation && !['get', 'post'].contains(method)){
        var _method = '_method=' + method;
        data = (data) ? _method + '&' + data : _method;
        method = 'post';
    }

    if (this.options.urlEncoded && ['post', 'put'].contains(method)){
        var encoding = (this.options.encoding) ? '; charset=' + this.options.encoding : '';
        this.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' + encoding;
    }

    if (!url) url = document.location.pathname;

    var trimPosition = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (trimPosition > -1 && (trimPosition = url.indexOf('#')) > -1) url = url.substr(0, trimPosition);

    if (this.options.noCache)
        url += (url.contains('?') ? '&' : '?') + String.uniqueID();

    if (data && method == 'get'){
        url += (url.contains('?') ? '&' : '?') + data;
        data = null;
    }

    var xhr = this.xhr;
    if (progressSupport){
        xhr.onloadstart = this.loadstart.bind(this);
        xhr.onprogress = this.progress.bind(this);
    }

    xhr.open(method.toUpperCase(), url, this.options.async, this.options.user, this.options.password);
    if (this.options.user && 'withCredentials' in xhr) xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = this.onStateChange.bind(this);

    Object.each(this.headers, function(value, key){
        try {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
        } catch (e){
            this.fireEvent('exception', [key, value]);
        }
    }, this);

    this.fireEvent('request');
    xhr.send(data);
    if (!this.options.async) this.onStateChange();
    if (this.options.timeout) this.timer = this.timeout.delay(this.options.timeout, this);
    return this;
}
```

At the place I have marked, the method seems to add some extra data to the requests. I thought that this would be a good place to add my code. I could overwrite the method to include something like this:

```
if (_USER_ID_TO_EDIT){
    var id= 'userIdToEdit=' + _USER_ID_TO_EDIT;
data = (data) ? id+ '&' + data : id;
}
```

However, this isn't a great solution because it means that if there is any changes to the send() function in the library, my code will become out of sync (I like to use the latest library version.)

Is there a better way to do this (and would my method here even work)? How can I add content to all requests sent by the `Request` class without changing ~20 .js files and ~100 uses of this class elsewhere on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erm, I would question how trustworthy this practice would be but in any case, you can just use a special instance of Request for your admin:

```
Request.admin = new Class({

    Extends: Request,

    initialize: function(options) {
       this.parent(options);
    },

    send: function(options) {
        // example, add to the data being sent admin id and a delay 
        options = Object.merge({
            data: {
                adminid: "foo",
                delay: 5 // testing with 5 sec delay
            }
        }, options || this.options);
        this.parent(options);
    }

});

new Request.admin({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: "<p>original data here. foobar</p>"        
    },
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function() {
        document.id('target').set("html", this.response.text);
    }
}).send();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/x2pBu/

I would consider this the better practice. You'd also need to override the `.get` method.

Another solution is to change the Request prototype itself by refactoring it, not editing it directly - you can use `Class.refactor` from mootools-more or `Request.implement({send: ... });` so all subclasses of Request benefit from it (Request.HTML and Request.JSON and Request.Queue etc).

You can even do `var orig = Request.prototype.send; Request.prototype.send = function() {... something to options; orig.call(this, options); }` etc etc.

Downside to this kind of change is that you get unexpected behavior in your Request class (i.e. a mootools dev that expects certain things to happen will get caught out, data will go out w/o them knowing about it, validators may fail, etc etc). It may be difficult to debug. Having it as an implicit extended class makes sense from maintenance standpoint also, minimal abstraction.

don't worry too much about future compatibility - mootools 2.0 (aka MILK) will go the AMD way and old mootools code will be obsolete from compatibility standpoint, though the API will remain). There probably won't be many more releases in the 1.4 branch.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use the first thing you suggest. With regards to trustworthyness/security, I will validate that the logged in user has the right to edit other peoples' details on the server, so hopefully this won't be unsecure.